# How do I load Vuex data before a component is rendered?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm calling a weather API in a vuex module. What I'd like to accomplish is to fetch the data using a computed property in my component.
With the current setup, there are no issues except that I need to refresh/reload the page for the vuex state to be updated. I have tried dispatching the action of getting the data inside a mounted hook, but that doesn't work either, and so the page has to manually be reloaded in order for the computed properties to be assigned the with the data.
What is the correct way to do this ?

Vuex store.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import {
  Auth
} from 'aws-amplify';
import axios from 'axios';

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var AWSCognito = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

Auth.currentUserInfo

var data = {
    UserPoolId: '******************',
    ClientId: '******************',
  },
  userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoUserPool(data);

var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();

AWS.config.region = '******************';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const weatherService = {
  state: () => ({
    error: null,
    currentTemp: '',
    minTemp: '',
    maxTemp: '',
    sunrise: '',
    sunset: '',
    pressure: '',
    humidity: '',
    wind: '',
    overcast: '',
    name: '',
    latitude: '',
    longitude: '',
  }),
  mutations: {
    SET_WEATHER_DATA(state, payload) {
      state.currentTemp = payload.main.temp;
      state.minTemp = payload.main.temp_min + '°C';
      state.maxTemp = payload.main.temp_max + '°C';
      state.pressure = payload.main.pressure + 'hPa';
      state.humidity = payload.main.humidity + '%';
      state.wind = payload.wind.speed + 'm/s';
      state.overcast = payload.weather[0].description;
      state.sunrise = new Date(payload.sys.sunrise * 1000)
        .toLocaleTimeString('en-GB')
        .slice(0, 5);
      state.sunset = new Date(payload.sys.sunset * 1000)
        .toLocaleTimeString('en-GB')
        .slice(0, 5);
      state.name = payload.name;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    getWeather({
      commit
    }) {
      try {
        if (cognitoUser != null) {
          cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, session) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              return;
            }
            AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
              IdentityPoolId: '******************',
              Logins: {
                // Change the key below according to the specific region your user pool is in.
                'cognito-idp.******************.amazonaws.com/******************': session
                  .getIdToken()
                  .getJwtToken(),
              },
            });

            AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
              if (!err) {
                var id = AWS.config.credentials.identityId;
                // Instantiate aws sdk service objects now that the credentials have been updated
                var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
                  region: AWS.config.region,
                });
                var params = {
                  //
                };

                params.ProjectionExpression = "user_meta_data";

                docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
                  if (err) console.error(err);
                  else {
                    console.log(data);
                    const lat = data.Items[0].user_meta_data.coordinates.latitude
                    const long = data.Items[0].user_meta_data.coordinates.longitude

                    axios
                      .get(
                        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' +
                        lat +
                        '&lon=' +
                        long +
                        '&units=metric&APPID=' +
                        process.env.VUE_APP_OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY
                      )
                      .then((response) => {
                        commit('SET_WEATHER_DATA', response.data)
                        console.log("dispatched!")
                      })
                      .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                      });
                  }
                });
              }
            });
          });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return;
      }

    }
  },

  getters: {
    weatherGetter(state) {
      return state
    },
  },

};


const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    w: weatherService
  },
  state: {
    //
  },
  mutations: {
    //
  },

  actions: {
    //
  },

  getters: {
    //
  },

});

export default store;
```

Weather.vue component

```
<template>
  <!-- <div>
  <v-card> {{ weatherGetter }} </v-card>
  </div>
</template>
    
<script>    
export default {
  data() {
    return {
    };
  },
  computed: {
    weatherGetter() {
      return this.$store.getters('weatherGetter');
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getWeather');
  };
</script>
```

I looked at other similar issues and they seemed to suggest using beforeRouteEnter, which I don't think will be ideal in my case.
I also tried dispatching the action in a created hook in main.js, to no avail.

Comment: If you want to make the AJAX call before the very first rendering - you should use the `beforeMount` hook. If you want to also catch all subsequent re-renders then you should also use the `beforeUpdate` hook.

Comment: I've tried both hooks, didn't get the data.

Comment: You will get the data when the AJAX call completes - but at that time Vue will probably have already rendered the component, so the data arrival will trigger re-render.

Comment: I think the problem why your application isn't re-rendering, is that you're retrieving the whole `state` in your getter... I know that in newer versions of Vue and Vuex, the reactive is way better to the point that it'd recognizes a change in an array or a sub attribute. But the first thing I'd recommend you to do is: create a attribute called weather in your state, and in your mutation, set a whole new object to this attribute when the data is retrieved, then in your getter you only return the `state.weather`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But it's most likely not due to returning the whole state. I've even tried returning only one attribute in the getter and the mutation. Also the issue is not about re-rendering, the data is not even loaded into the computed properties on the first page load. Strangely I can see in the console that the action is dispatched, but for some reason the computed properties don't receive the data. But when the page is reloaded, that's when they get the data.

Comment: If it helps, I must add that I have a login component. What happens after login is that it does a router.push to the homepage, where the weather component lies. Not sure what router.push does exactly in terms of hooks, but that might have to do with something with the computed or mounted hooks not being executed once user is 'pushed' to the new page.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your issue?

```
<template>
  <div v-if="weatherGetter">
  <v-card> {{ weatherGetter }} </v-card>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: does your getter have the value that you want?

Answer (score 0):

Using mapActions seems to do it.

So in the component we will have

```
<template>
  <!-- <div>
  <v-card> {{ weatherGetter }} </v-card>
  </div>
</template>
    
<script>    
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';


export default {
  data() {
    return {
    };
  },
methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      getWeather: 'getWeather',
    }),
},
  computed: {
    weatherGetter() {
      return this.$store.getters('weatherGetter');
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getWeather();
  };
</script>
```